# .htaccess rewrite rule to point to 2 different files

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following structure:

```
site.com/organizer
```

where `organizer` is a variable and

```
site.com/organizer/event
```

where `event` is also a variable

When someone accesses `/organizer` I want it to point to `organizer.php?name=$1`

When someone accesses `/organizer/event` I want it to point to `event.php?organizer=$1&event=$2`.

I was able to do either the first one or second one but never together. They seem to overwrite eachother.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ event.php?organizer=$1&event=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ organizer.php?name=$1 [QSA]
```

Also even though I added above it:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

It seems that all my CSS, JavaScript, images, etc files in separate folders don't point to the right path anymore.

How can I solve both these problems?

Comment: give an example url of an js or css file that is getting rewritten plz

Comment: I just fixed the urls for the files. I added a '/' before them when calling them like: href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" instead of href="css/bootstrap.min.css"

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it myself like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ event.php?organizer=$1&event=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ organizer.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I had to put the conditions again for the second rule.

Also for the URLs to files being rewritten, I fixed it by added a slash in front of them when calling them like this:

`href="/css/bootstrap.min.css"`

instead of

```
href="css/bootstrap.min.css"
```